# Either/Or Relationship in Database design improvement

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2012, relational-database

I have following either/Or relationship in my model. Following requirements are catered in model

- Plan Is made for certain length of period 3 months, 6 months yearly etc
- Plan may have revision In revision length of Period will not be
  changed
- Planning will be either at SKU level or SKU Group level
- Each  SKU Group have many SKUs
- Planning will be done at either SKU Group level or at SKU Level

In my design I made SKUID `nullable` in item table if Plan is at Group level. How can I improve the design

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I could get from the description:

- PeriodTypeID should be also included in Plans (or Revisions) - this is to make clear what periods the plan will work with.
- PlanItems.SKUGroupID may be NULLable (for SKU-level planning). You can even add a check constraint to make sure exactly one of (SKUGroupID, SKUID) is filled in.
- SKUs should have a foreign key referencing SKUGroups.SKUGroupId

Hope that helps.